# Magento 1.9: Google Tag Manager code add in header But active Only on Product Detail Page

Tags: magento-1.9, google-analytics

I want to add the script in the head.phtml but i need the product's id, SKU. So i only want it to work when is on the product Detail page.

Comment: You can setup rules in google tag manager so it only triggers on the the product page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution:

```
$_product = Mage::registry("current_product")
    if ($_product && $_product->getId()) :
        //google tag code here
    endif;
```